# Trying to do a temperature converter put can't figure out to get out of loop when pressing specific key

Tags: python

I'm learning python right now and one of the exercice is to do a temperature converter. You ask user to pick an operation (for example from C to F), then to enter a number. The correct number is then shown. I get that part, but next we need to add "Q" to the choice, so when the user press it, the loop stops. Since this exercice is part of the loop section, I guess I'm supposed to use a while, but I can't figure out how.

Here's my code right now :

```
conversion = input("""Choose your operation.
                        Choices :
                        1. C to F
                        2. F to C
                        3. C to K
                        4. K to C
                        5. F to K
                        6. K to F
                        Q. Quit
                        Your choice : """)
chiffre = float(input("Enter your temperature : "))


            
if conversion == "1":
    resultat = (f"{chiffre*(9/5)+32}°F")                   
elif conversion == "2":
    resultat = (f"{(chiffre-32)*(5/9)}°C")       
elif conversion == "3":
    resultat = (f"{chiffre+273.15}°K")        
elif conversion == "4":
    resultat = (f"{chiffre-273.15}°C")  
elif conversion == "5":
    resultat = (f"{(5/9)*(chiffre+459.67)}°K")
elif conversion == "6":
    resultat = (f"{(chiffre-273.15)*(9/5) + 32}°F")
print(f"Your result is {resultat}")
```

I tried while True in the beginning but as expected it give me an infinite loop.

Comment: First thing first, you'll have to not try to run `float("Q")`... See e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops.

Comment: `True` condition is, expectedly, always met. Can you think of condition that would be met only when user doesn't input `"Q"`?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of using `while True:` is good. I'm assuming that part of the assignment here is understanding not only how to set up a loop, but also how to exit the loop conditionally. You just need to test for the `"Q"` entry inside your loop and `break` if it's found. Adding this code before you do any further logic inside the loop would probably make the most sense, so we can test as soon as we get the input into the `conversion` variable:

```
while True:
  conversion = input("""Choose your operation.
                        Choices :
                        1. C to F
                        2. F to C
                        3. C to K
                        4. K to C
                        5. F to K
                        6. K to F
                        Q. Quit
                        Your choice : """)
  #break the loop if they choose to quit
  if conversion == "Q":
    break

  chiffre = float(input("Enter your temperature : "))

            
  if conversion == "1":
    resultat = (f"{chiffre*(9/5)+32}°F")                   
  elif conversion == "2":
    resultat = (f"{(chiffre-32)*(5/9)}°C")       
  elif conversion == "3":
    resultat = (f"{chiffre+273.15}°K")        
  elif conversion == "4":
    resultat = (f"{chiffre-273.15}°C")  
  elif conversion == "5":
    resultat = (f"{(5/9)*(chiffre+459.67)}°K")
  elif conversion == "6":
    resultat = (f"{(chiffre-273.15)*(9/5) + 32}°F")
  print(f"Your result is {resultat}")
```

Comment: Thank you ! I tried my while True at the same place, but the problem for me was positionning the break. I put it in the end and as expected, it wasn't doing the trick. Breaking it at that point seems so simple and obvious now...

Comment: If it's any solace, that's how everything in programming is when you are learning: confusing and frustrating until it's obvious and you feel silly for not getting it sooner. If you are feeling confused and frustrated, then you are on the right path. Also, for future questions, it would help if you put your non-working attempt (especially for homework questions). then we know where to focus and guide.